# MIT/GNU Scheme Won't Start

Tags: ubuntu, lisp

I built MIT Scheme from source using GCC on Ubuntu 14.04, but attempting to run it gives me an error

```
mit-scheme: can't find a readable default for option --band.
    searched for file all.com in these directories:
    /home/tay/Downloads
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, adding `export MITSCHEME_LIBRARY_PATH=~/mit-scheme-plugins:/usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64` to the bash profile fixes this.